# AddPersistentListener onclick events not being persistent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, event-handling

I have an array with something like 100 buttons that each need to have an OnClick event added to them which refers to another, mirroring, 100 objects. Of course, I could do this by hand, but instead, I tried to create an Editor script that would do it for me. I've run into several problems:

1) onClick.AddListener isn't working. It only creates an empty onClick call. This is my code for this:

```
leds[i].onClick.AddListener(delegate { AddClickEvent(ledsCopy[i]); });
```

2) I've tried to use UnityEventTools, both by creating a UnityAction and just using AddPersistentListener (Object and Bool):

```
UnityEventTools.AddBoolPersistentListener(leds[i].onClick, ledsCopy[i].SetActive, true);
```

With UnityAction:

```
UnityAction<GameObject> callback = new UnityAction<GameObject>(AddClickEvent);
UnityEditor.Events.UnityEventTools.AddObjectPersistentListener<GameObject>(leds[i].onClick, callback, ledsCopy[i]);
```

The UnityEventTools and UnityAction method "works", but only while in the Editor. If I let it execute in edit mode, then turn the generating script off, my onClick events disappear. If I try to build my game with this script on, it will either not build because of Editor scripts, or ignore them, so my buttons end up with no onClick events.

I haven't been able to find anything similar to what I'm experiencing, and no documentation about this being an expected behaviour of AddPersistentListener or not. It's also my first time using Editor scripts, so if I'm doing something wrong, or there's another way to do this, please do tell me! Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:** the full script, as asked

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor.Events;
#endif

//#if UNITY_EDITOR 
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class SetButtonEvents : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Button[] leds = new Button[64];
    public GameObject[] ledsCopy = new GameObject[64];

    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < leds.Length; i++)
        {
            leds[i] = transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(i).GetComponent<Button>();
            ledsCopy[i] = transform.GetChild(1).GetChild(i).GetChild(0).gameObject;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < leds.Length; i++)
        {
            //UnityAction<GameObject> callback = new UnityAction<GameObject>(AddClickEvent);
            // UnityEditor.Events.UnityEventTools.AddObjectPersistentListener<GameObject>(leds[i].onClick, callback, ledsCopy[i]);
            //UnityEditor.Events.UnityEventTools.AddObjectPersistentListener<GameObject>(leds[i].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Button>().onClick, callback, ledsCopy[i]);
#if UNITY_EDITOR
            UnityEventTools.AddBoolPersistentListener(leds[i].onClick, ledsCopy[i].SetActive, true);
            UnityEventTools.AddBoolPersistentListener(leds[i].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Button>().onClick, ledsCopy[i].SetActive, false);
#else
            leds[i].onClick.AddListener(delegate { AddClickEvent(ledsCopy[i]); });
            leds[i].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(delegate { AddClickEvent(ledsCopy[i]); });
#endif
        }
    }

    void AddClickEvent(GameObject objectToActivate)
    {
        if (objectToActivate.activeSelf)
            objectToActivate.SetActive(false);
        else
            objectToActivate.SetActive(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: could you show how exactly your editor script looks like?

Comment: I'll edit and add the whole thing if you think it'll help, but it's literally just the code I wrote above inside a loop going through my objects in the Start() of the class

Comment: wait so no Editor script? Did you test it because even so you won't see any callback added in the inspector the buttons should still work. (speaking about the AddListener method)

Comment: I edited showing what I have in my script. And yes, I did test, and AddListener doesn't work

Comment: I don't understand what your script is supposed to do ... wouldn't it be easier to work with a prefab and simply instatiate 64 instances of it? I can't test your script directly since I don't have the hierachy ... however using `AddBoolPersistentListener` in the editor works for me and stays persistent also later in playmode the problem: It even adds it again and again everytime `Start` is called in editmode... But when you already added it persistent you shouldn't add it again using `AddListener`

Comment: I'm only adding it twice because the editor one isn't persistent, that's my whole issue. It disappears if the script that generated it disappears (either by me deleting it or by building). Also the problem of the prefab approach is that it's 64 buttons that reference 64 other different objects, so even if I copy the buttons, I'll have to change the references manually...

Comment: couldn't you setup 1 prefab with all references itself needs included (for just enabling diabling you still could use an empty gameobject and later instantiate different childobjects depending on some settings or enum etc) and than you setup the onclick event once and just instantiate that prefab 64 times (not even on runtime)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how exactly you want to set that up, but yeah, maybe I could find a workaround of the sorts (even if it seems hard to me, as the buttons and the objects they reference to can't be children/parent, they're each in two separate grid layouts). But, to be honest, at this point I'm also wondering why I can't add listeners like that in my project, and I'd like to see if someone has an answer for that. Maybe some day I'll need to do it and won't have any sort of work around....

Comment: Just to be sure here: You do not replace the `leds` in another script e.g. by instantiating etc at anytime, right?